# Get clicks from activity button in multiple fragments

Tags: android, button, callback, fragment, listener

I have two **fragments**. In each fragment have some methods which are doing different functions. I'd like to get **click** event of **toolbar** **button** from host **Activity**. I have researched for answer, found some solutions like

```
button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbarButton)
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But when i use this way, it only returns second fragment method.

Comment: Do you want get click of activity  toolbar in  Fragment ?

Comment: @sukhbir i can get this view. Also buttons which are in toolbar. But i can't handle them in fragment. When i use click listener of this button, i receive only second fragment's click event.

Comment: You need to override click of toolbar buttons in activtiy only and in on click  you need to check  this `Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            if (fragment instanceof Yourfragment) {
                      
        }`

Comment: @sukhbir explain your answer, please.

Comment: Please wait i am going to  explain in comment.

Answer (score 0):

get fragments instance using fragmentManager in Activity and cast it to your fragment, then you can call any method of each fragment.so you can use it in toolbar click listener
example in new activity add this;

```
FirstFragmet frag1 = (FirstFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag1);
SecondFragmet frag2 = (SecondFragmet) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frag2);
findViewById(R.id.someBtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             frag1.someMethod; //or
             frag2.someMethod;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `click` of `toolbar buttons` in `activtiy` only and in `onClick()` you need to check this

**HostActivity**

```
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toolbarButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

            if (fragment instanceof FragmentA) {
                FragmentA objFragmentA = (FragmentA) fragment;
                objFragmentA.callMethod();
            } else if (fragment instanceof FragmentB) {
                FragmentB objFragmentB = (FragmentB) fragment;
                objFragmentB.callMethod();
            }


        }
    });
```

If you want to get Reference of current `Fragment` using `viewPager`. You can get achieve this by using below code

```
 if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        FragmentA frag1 = (FragmentA) viewPager
                .getAdapter()
                .instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        frag1.call();
    } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
        FragmentB frag2 = (FragmentB) viewPager
                .getAdapter()
                .instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
        frag2.call();
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: i'm not using replace method. I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter.